# Router startup problem

Tags: router, connection

I have problems with my Tilgin Vood Router. As I try to start my router by turning the power on (captain obvious), it generally doesn't work the first 3-4 times. This is getting very annoying.

Five minutes after turning the power on the router's signal LEDs don't blink in the way they should do in a connected state. I can connect to my routers web configuration interface through my PC connected to it via LAN though I can't access the internet.

It usually takes the router five minutes to get to the point where it should be connected to the internet but as it doesn't work the first times.

So I turn on my router 3-5 times, let him work 5 minutes and then suddenly, after turning the power off and on again it all works.

The problem is regarding startup only, when I get it to work everything runs as smooth as a 1980-s text-based C++ game on a 3ghz machine.

I also have to restart my PC too in order for everything to work.

- How can I solve this problem?
- Just leave the router turned on all time? I prefer a daily IP switch, though.
- May the problem have something to do with my PC? There is another one connected to the router too and it doesn't work there either.