# Router startup problems

Tags: internet, router, reboot, led

I have problems with my Tilgin Vood Router.
As I try to start my router by turning the power on (captain obvious), it generally doesn't work the first 3-4 times. This is getting very annoying.

Five minutes after turning the power on the router's signal LEDs don't blink in the way they should do in a connected state. I can connect to my routers web configuration interface through my PC connected to it via LAN though I can't access the internet.

It usually takes the router five minutes to get to the point where it should be connected to the internet but as it doesn't work the first times.

So I turn on my router 3-5 times, let him work 5 minutes and then suddenly, after turning the power off and on again it all works.

I also have to restart my PC too in order for everything to work.

- How can I solve this problem?
- Just leave the router turned on all time? I prefer a daily IP switch, though.
- May the problem have something to do with my PC? There is another one connected to the router too and it doesn't work there either.

Comment: Tilgin Vood routers all appear to be SOHO DSL ones. In that case, if you don't have a "static IP" service activated, your provider will not allow a PPPoE session to last more than one day and will forcibly disconnect you, thus updating the IP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Router startup problem](https://superuser.com/questions/119163/router-startup-problem)

Answer (score 1):

From what you are saying, it is obvious to me, that you are having a hardware problem with the router. Its most likely broken, so you should replace it, or try out different router in place, to exclude any other options.

Another possability in could be a problem with router power supply. You might check out different one, if its possible in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a hardware problem with the router (if it does turn on in the end, something is amiss with the circuitry, IMHO).
I would just leave it on. You can trigger a router IP release/renew every 24 hours if you must have a new IP. You can even add a task to do it automatically via a script.
But depending on the router's age/price, I'd just go ahead and replace it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a SOHO router, or a business class one? When you say you have to turn it on 3-4 times, does that mean pressing the power button the first time does nothing? How do you know? What indications does the router have that it is in fact powered on?

If the answer to the second question there is yes, likely you have a hardware issue.

To answer the other question, it should never be turned off. Depends though on how it is being used. If it is just at home, doesn't matter. In any kind of an office setting (no matter how small) it should never be turned off. Most business routers are meant to run all the time in a powered on state.

I have never worked on that brand, but some Cisco model routers take a long time to boot. Even the small ones. So is it possible you just are not giving it enough time after the first initial power on to boot up?